# Hc05 Bluetooth Auto reset to default values

Tags: bluetooth, hc-05

I am using HC-05 with a Gps module to make a Bluetooth GPS.
and i am using 5v mobile charger from the power supply.
also using a B0505S-1WR3 Mornsun 5V to 5V DC-DC Converter for further power isolation.

This board is used inside the marine boat and they already have a 24v to 230V AC home ups. The usb adapter is connected to that ups and they working fine, but some time the bluetooth module is resetted to its default value.
i cant find the cause and i through it may be caused by voltage surge and i used the SMAJ5.0CA TVS diode at the 5v input to the board, but still i got the same problems.

What may be the problem which resets the HC05 to its default values automatically. Is there any pin which causes the HC05 to its default values?

Comment: There are many HC05 clones with bad firmware around. My first attempt would be to try one from another vendor. The original HC05 modules I use, run 24/7 for >5 years now, I have more than 600 of them out in the field. But this year I received many bad working fakes.

Comment: Most likely power supply isn't powerful enough, causing the device to sometimes reset POR. Try to replace the power supply with a better one and add big caps before the module.